# What is the correct way to handle "answer plagiarism"?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, plagiarism

Example:

- User A gives a not-great but working answer
- User A gets upvotes
- User A gets accepted answer
- User B gives the quantifiably best possible answer
- User B gets more upvotes
- User A edits answer to include answer B

Is this acceptable by the SE community? I can think of pros & cons for each.

**How should this be handled?**

[*The question that spurred this thought*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986129/play-multiple-css-animations-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Certainly a tad suspicious. I've seen it argued though that code that short is easy to independently come up with.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... looks like a dupe - marked

Comment: the linked duplicate talks about case with no attribution. if attribution is made, is this then acceptable?